# cm^-1 and ns^-1 relationship

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, unit-conversion

In my [last Phys.SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207008/2451) Emilio Pisanty mentioned this relationship $1 cm^{-1} = 10^n c^{-1} ns^{-1}$. I was wondering where this relationship came from. Does anybody know? Second of all, I am not sure how from this relationship, it can be derived that in natural units, $1 cm^{-1} = 30 ns^{-1}$. Can I have a clear derivation of this? I understand in natural units, the c vanishes, so is should be $1 cm^{-1} = 10^n ns^{-1}$, not $30 ns^{-1}$. So how is this derived?

Before downvoting, please tell me what you think is wrong with the question.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: You'll find the problem less troubling if you invert both sides. That way you won't have to reason about negative exponents (which shouldn't be harder but actually engender dumb mistakes all too often).

Comment: *Why the downvote?* because it's kinda trivial? $c=2.9979\times10^{10}\text cm/s$, convert from seconds to nanoseconds and what do you have?

Comment: Im talking about natural units, @KyleKanos

Comment: In natural units, length and time both have units of 1/eV, so the point remains: it's still pretty trivial.

Comment: @KyleKanos Perhaps, but [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0208093) suggests that there are many who don't understand this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do natural units the other way around. Suppose that we've always worked with natural units, we measure time and distances in the same units and then some crazy physicist comes along who puts in factors of c in equations, e.g.

$$ds^2 = dt^2 - dx^2 - dy^2 - dz^2 \longrightarrow c^2 dt^2 - dx^2 - dy^2 - dz^2$$

He then defines a meter and a second such that:

$c = 1 = 299792458 \text{ meters/second} $

This then means that:

1 meter = 1/299792458 seconds.

Or:

cm = 1/29979245800 seconds

Therefore:

$$\text{cm}^{-1} = 29979245800 \text{ second}^{-1} = 29.9792458 \text{ ns}^{-1} $$

Answer (score 1):

The point of natural units is to rescale your units so that $c = 1$ and $\hbar = 1$ and $k_B = 1$. This is technically a type error because the quantities on both sides have different dimension, but it means "in the dimensions that give this the appropriate size." So this means that you have a $\text{cm time}$ unit, for example, which is the time it takes for light to travel $\text{1 cm},$ about 33.36 picoseconds. Similarly, the $\text{cm}^{-1}\text{ frequency}$ unit is (1000/33.36) $= 29.979 \text{ ns}^{-1}.$

The $10^n$ appears to be your invention but works perfectly well as long as you allow non-integer $n$.

Comment: But then these dimensions are a human construct, it's just a convention to assign them in the way we conventionally do.